# Why do images look sharp on my camera's LCD, but not tack sharp on my laptop?

Tags: sharpness, rear-lcd, preview, image-review

I am using a Sigma 18-35mm f1.8 Art lens on a Nikon D7100. On appropriate settings, I see sharp images after pressing the zoom button once, but not before doing that. When I review them on a laptop, though, I can't find images that are as tack sharp as they appear as reviewed on LCD of camera, after pressing zoom.

There is no unnecessary mistakes in garden pictures in shade, with sweet spot, image size comes to 20 MB approx, image setting Raw or Large Fine....
Sometimes I get better image with Nikon 18-140mm.... I am worried but can't find the right solution.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add at least one example image.

Comment: What settings are you using? Are you using a tripod? You say that there are "no unnecessary mistakes", but... are you sure?

Comment: What's a **necessary** mistake? :-) .  OK, seriously, what are your shutter and aperture settings? Have you tried Manual focus?

Comment: I think the duplicate questions here provide good basic information on how to get sharp images, but nominate this for reopening to cover simply the question of LCD review vs. pixel-peeping later.

Answer (score 2):

When reviewing photos on your camera's LCD screen be aware that it will **lie like a politician!** On the camera's smaller, lower resolution screen depth of field will appear much deeper than it will when viewed at full size and resolution on your laptop.

Preview images displayed on your camera's LCD screen are also sharpened and usually have a bit (or more) of contrast and saturation added to give them a little "punch". Hey, the camera manufacturers want that preview image to look incredible when you make a sample snapshot under the crappy light at the camera store! If you are saving your files in raw format and opening them with most raw convertor applications, the default rendering used to open the file will likely have far less sharpening and contrast applied than the jpeg preview generated in your camera and displayed on the camera's LCD.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as above. 
One way you can 'try' and deal with this to a degree is to zoom right in when reviewing your pictures on the LCD and look how shape they are.

They will still be an aspect of your image being 'flattered' by the screen but it will be harder for it to be hidden.

Comment: What more are you trying to say regarding Michael's answer ? This answer should probably be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The screen on the camera is smaller so the pixels are denser, closer together, making it appear sharp.

As above ,a good trick is to zoom in on the camera viewer to check it's still sharp when closer in.

Using a faster shutter speed and/or higher ISO may give you a better chance of getting a sharper photo.

Comment: *The screen on the camera is smaller so the pixels are denser, closer together, making it appear sharp* : it implies that the camera screen and the monitor have the same definition. It is probably never the case.