# How do I get the first preview on my camera to look as good as when I'm zoomed in?

Tags: resolution, sharpening

When I take photos on my camera and view them, they sometimes don't look the best quality. When I zoom into them on the camera they look much better, like the quality and sharpness of the image is a lot better zoomed in than when first previewed.

Why is this and how can I get the image to look as good normally like when the image is zoomed in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do my images look different on my camera than when imported to my laptop?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/69657/why-do-my-images-look-different-on-my-camera-than-when-imported-to-my-laptop)

Comment: @mattdm I understand the rationale that duplicate questions should be avoided, but sometimes I think the hunt for a duplicate is a bit too zealous, and the duplication tenuous. This question is about apparent sharpness at different zoom levels on a camera monitor. The other question is about colour differences between camera and computer screen.

Comment: If there is a way to change this, it will depend on your camera. Please put this information in your question.

Comment: @osullic Basic answer is the same. The LCD screen isn't a great representation of the actual image. That said, I'm sure we've had something closer than that one before, too.

Comment: Try: [Why do images look sharp on my camera's LCD, but not tack sharp on my laptop?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/77890/why-do-images-look-sharp-on-my-cameras-lcd-but-not-tack-sharp-on-my-laptop/83521#83521)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do images look sharp on my camera's LCD, but not tack sharp on my laptop?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/77890/why-do-images-look-sharp-on-my-cameras-lcd-but-not-tack-sharp-on-my-laptop)

Answer (score 6):

It is because the camera is previewing a compressed JPEG on screen with lower resolution than the actual image is.

The algorithm of downsampling the image is sometimes too rough to show a nice image. When you zoom in, you are actually zooming out less, the downsampling is not that rough and the result is closer to the "reality".

This is not a concern at all because what one really cares about is not camera preview but the image after postprocessing displayed in your portfolio or printed on a wall.

I use the camera preview for really rough evaluation: Do I have everything in the frame? Is it too underexposed/overexposed? Was the shutter fast enough?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56994/discussion-between-crowley-and-myridium).